# Nutch as stand-by spider with custom processing pipelines

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I would like to use Apache Nutch as a spider which only fetches given url list (no crawling). The urls are going to be stored in Redis and I want Nutch to take constantly pop them from the list and fetch html. The spider needs to be in stand-by mode - it always waits for the new urls coming into Redis until the user decides to stop the job. Also, I would like to apply my own processing pipelines to the extracted html files (not only text extraction). Is it possible to do with Nutch?

Answer (score 1):

StormCrawler would be a much better fit for achieving this - it was designed to be able to cater for scenarios like the one you described. You'd need to write a custom spout t connect to redis, reuse the fetcher and parser bolts then add bolts with your own processing. Some of SC's early users were doing exactly that